# Sizing problem with WPF's grid layout

Tags: wpf

Here's my problem. I have three controls in a row (they capture people's names). The controls themselves size themselves to an appropriate size. I want to space these three controls horizontally to be evenly spaced along the line. This bit is easy:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="2" Height="50" Width="50" />
  <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="2" Height="50" Width="50" />
  <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" BorderThickness="2" Height="50" Width="50" />
</Grid>
```

The problem comes when I want to hide the second entry. If I set its visibility to collapsed, I would want the two remaining items to be equally spaced. This does not happen, the middle column remains at 1/3 of the grid's width.

I have tried various combinations of grids and stackpanels but cannot find a way around this. I am trying to find a fairly generic solution as this situation may arise again.

Visually, it should look like:

```
   +----------------------------------------------+
   | +------------+ +------------+ +------------+ |
   | |aardvark    | |beatle      | |cat         | |
   | +------------+ +------------+ +------------+ |
   +----------------------------------------------+
```

Note that the inner boxes use the width=* to size them to 1/3 but the controls inside the boxes are not stretched.

Comment: what are you setting to collapsed?  the border element shown in this xaml with a hardcoded width of 50 or the child of the border?

Comment: For the purposes of testing, I'm just collapsing the border using the example above. If I can get a simple case working, then I'll then try and get my app working the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving the problem.

```
  <Grid>   
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource collapsed2auto}}"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />  
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>   
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>    
     <RowDefinition />   
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>   
   <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="2" Height="50" Width="50" />   
   <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="2" Height="50" Width="50" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsVisible}"/>   
   <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" BorderThickness="2" Height="50" Width="50" /> 
  </Grid>
```

This feels like the least hacky solution. basically, it takes the same property used to disable the control, transforms it into a "*" or "auto" via a converter and assigns it to the column definition. Seems to work.

I had also considered building a trigger to do the same, but this feels cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still get the same problem if you change all 3 :

`<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />`

For Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.columndefinition.width%28VS.96%29.aspx

Comment: That setting will make all the fields take up only the space they need which might be different sizes.

Comment: Yep, I'd tried auto - it does not space things out. Similarly, I've tried stackpanels with horizontalalignment = stretch (no joy) .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting Visibility, set the Width of the `ColumnDefinition` to 0

suppose the name of the grid is grid1 then

```
grid1.ColumnDefinitions[1].Width = new GridLength(0);
```

Comment: That works (as does setting width="auto"), though I was trying to avoid coding hacks. Possibly, I could set up a trigger to do this. i.e.: if one of the controls is collapsed then automatically set its column width to 0/auto.